# No internet connection Ubuntu-WSL while VPN

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have a Ubuntu-20.04 Version 2 WSL running on my Windows 10 Laptop. Everything works fine, I have internet connection. But only as long as I am not connected to a VPN network.

If I connect to my the network of my university using Cisco AnyConnect, I can no longer connect to the internet on WSL, while everything works fine using e.g. firefox in the windows system. I get: ping: google.de: Temporary failure in name resolution

I already tried the following:

Open windows cmd in admin mode and type these commands:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns
reboot
```

That worked once, I had access to the internet. But as soon as I disconnected the VPN connection and connected again, I had the same problem all over again. I tried to just execute the commands again and rebooted, but now thats not working anymore.

So I really do not know what else to do. I really need to use WSL while being connected via VPN

Comment: Nothing working for me, with CheckPoint Endpoint Security. Any specific hints for this one?

Comment: There's a new fix as of September 2023 -- please see [my answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1818812/893403).

Answer (score 39):

There is an issue with DNS Forwarding in WSL2 when using VPN ([see github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1350)). Plus there is a issue with the *Cisco AnyConnect*. So here is a workaround for these problems. Should work for Ubuntu and Debian.

### Workaround (new - automatic)

This solution is automatic and was created by **EdwardCooke** (see https://www.frakkingsweet.com/automatic-dns-configuration-with-wsl-and-anyconnect-client/). This is just the first part of his solution **updating resolv.conf when starting WSL.**

1. **Re-enable auto generation of resolv.conf** (if disabled)

   by commented the disable with `#`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf
   ```

   ```bash
   #[network]
   #generateResolvConf = false
   ```
2. **Create the script**

   ```bash
   sudo nano /bin/vpn-dns.sh
   ```

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   echo "Getting current DNS servers, this takes a couple of seconds"

   /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command '
   $ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
   Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Cisco AnyConnect*" | Get-DnsClientServerAddress | Select -ExpandProperty ServerAddresses
   Get-NetAdapter | ?{-not ($_.InterfaceDescription -like "Cisco AnyConnect*") } | Get-DnsClientServerAddress | Select -ExpandProperty ServerAddresses
   ' | \
           awk 'BEGIN { print "# Generated by vpn fix func on", strftime("%c"); print } { print "nameserver", $1 }' | \
           tr -d '\r' > /etc/resolv.conf
   clear
   ```
3. **Make it executable/run as sudo**

   ```bash
   sudo chmod +x /bin/vpn-dns.sh
   echo "$(whoami) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/vpn-dns.sh" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/010-$(whoami)-vpn-dns
   ```
4. Make it **run** on **wsl startup**

   ```bash
   echo "sudo /bin/vpn-dns.sh" | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/vpn-dns.sh
   ```

You can also run it manually:
`sudo /bin/vpn-dns.sh`

### Workaround (old manual)

1. Find out nameserver with **windows powershell** (during VPN Session)

   ```
   nslookup
   ```

   You'll get the IPv4 adress of your corporate nameserver
   Copy this address.
2. Disable *resolv.conf* generation **in wsl:**

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf
   ```

   copy this text to the file (to disable resolve.conf generation, when wsl starts up)

   ```bash
   [network]                                                                        
   generateResolvConf = false
   ```
3. **In wsl** Add your corporate nameserver to `resolv.conf`

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   Remove other entries and add your corporate nameserver IP (if you have a secondary nameserver, add it in a separate line)

   - `nameserver X.X.X.X` (where X.X.X.X is your address obtained in step 1)
4. Set your VPN adapter (if you have *Cisco AnyConnect*) **open a admin powershell**

   - Find out your VPN adapter name: `Get-NetIPInterface` (in my case: `"Cisco AnyConnect"`)
   - Set adapter metric (Replace -Match with your name), **in my case I have to run this after ever reboot or VPN reconnect**:

   ```
   Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
   ```

   ([What is interface metric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/automatic-metric-for-ipv4-routes): Used to determine route, windows use interface with lowest metric)
5. Restart wsl **in powershell**: `wsl.exe --shutdown`
6. Test it **in wsl** run: `wget google.com` - if this command works, you are done.

In my case I get DNS issues when try to connect to internal stuff via browser (on Windows 10, f.e.: intranet), caused by the high metric value set in step 4 (basically kind of disabling VPN Route). So here is the workaround for the workaround:

1. Check your default metric (of VPNs Interface) **in powershell** (replace -Match with your interface name)

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Get-NetIPInterface
```

2. When running into problems on Windows 10 restore this default value with **admin powershell** (replace value at the end with your default value):

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 1
```

Comment: This solution helped me! I didn't succeed using corporate DNS server found by `nslookup` but simply filling Google DNS server 8.8.8.8 in `/etc/resolv.conf` worked.

Comment: Can someone tell me what this does and why this is working? Is it a routing issue? How would one automate this to work automatically? (windows noob)

Comment: If you want to see the existing interface metrics you can use the PowerShell command `Get-NetIPInterface`

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MatMercer/f7e25b9c8ce7ca40dd3b220346136d23/raw/78638030f1e8522347eafd03c2eacdffd806c2f5/wsl-vpn-fix.sh captures this.  I had to  delete a dangling reference to  `/etc/resolve.conf` ; and use absolute path to `poweshell.exe `

Comment: `/etc/wsl.conf` change mentioned here has no real use . The resolv.conf will be recreated. [WSL 2 keeps overwriting resolv.conf ](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420).  The status says closed but I had to use work around mentioned in the same page

Comment: That's why `resolve.conf` generation is disabled in step 2

Comment: I'm sure it is my own fault, but I cannot get the workaround to work. It is frustrating that Microsoft still hasn't fixed this.

Comment: I just want to add that this is not necessarily limited to Cisco AnyConnect. This solution also works when connected through nordvpn.

Comment: Why would I get "/bin/vpn-dns.sh: line 11: /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied" when trying this script?

Comment: thanks @Kraego i love you man :)

Comment: two things to note about the automated answer: it should be clear that script has been specifically created for cisco any connect, and needs to be modified if you are using another VPN provider, such as Palo Alto Global Protect. for that example you would replace `Cisco AnyConnect*` with `PANGP*`

second, the script in `/etc/profile.d` needs to have `sudo` added to it.  `profile.d` runs as the user logging in, and the script needs to be invoked with elevated permissions.  This won't require a password input thanks to the step taken previously  in `sudoers`

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a bug in WSL 2, see https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277.

The workaround offered [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277#issuecomment-561649724) worked for me: Uninstall the Cisco AnyConnect client and install the version from the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/anyconnect/9wzdncrdj8lh).

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows 11 there was an update to WSL2 in September 2023 with (hopefully) a fix for this issue. Create a file `%UserProfile%\.wslconfig` with the content below, and then restart wsl. Run `wsl.exe --shutdown`. I also had to restart my computer but I am not sure if that is always necessary.

```
[experimental]
networkingMode=mirrored
dnsTunneling=true
```

After changing these settings restart WSL (i.e. run `wsl --shutdown`; just closing the running distribution isn't sufficient).

### Update 2024-02-27

These settings should now fall under `[wsl2]` instead of `[experimental]`.  [Related docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#main-wsl-settings)

References:

- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277#issuecomment-1724482809
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2023-update/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#main-wsl-settings

Comment: Unfortunately the `networkingMode=mirrored` and `dnsTunneling=true` settings only work if you're on Windows 11 :(

Comment: Thx really saved my day :D

Comment: I've just updated to windows 11 and I see these messages:

> wsl: Mirrored networking mode is not supported, falling back to NAT networking
> wsl: DNS Tunneling is not supported

Answer (score 3):

The easiest [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277#issuecomment-927855732) (before either Microsoft or Cisco come up with a permanent fix) is to launch WSL before connecting to the VPN:

```
wsl --shutdown
# disconnect VPN
wsl
# connect VPN again
```

Works on Windows 10 with WSL2+Ubuntu 20.04 and Cisco AnyConnect.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Also does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
**open** Microsoft Store -> **Search and Install** Anyconnect -> the vpn connection now works with WSL2.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your answer got flagged for review since it was your first post.  In my opinion, this needs a lot more detail.  The person asking the original question clearly had AnyConnect installed already, so telling them the answer is to install AnyConnect doesn't seem to make a lot of sense without more information.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i set VPN network interface metric to 6000 and both vpn and internet within wsl is now working:
`Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000`

Cisco AnyConnect mentioned in command above is my VPN. yours could be different. along with the metric number.

```
and then used following to fix the DNS:
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | tr -d '\r' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" | tr -d '\r' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

You can also put DNS fix into .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the VPN Ethernet Adaptor's DNS server settings are not taken by the WSL. These steps worked for me to add these settings manually:

1. cd ~/../../etc (go to etc folder in WSL).
2. echo "[network]" | sudo tee wsl.conf (Create wsl.conf file and add the first line).
3. echo "generateResolvConf = false" | sudo tee -a wsl.conf (Append wsl.conf the next line).
4. wsl -l (Get the . Debian-XX or Ubuntu-XX (Default) etc.)
5. wsl --terminate  (Terminate WSL in Windows cmd,  from the step 4).
6. cd ~/../../etc (go to etc folder in WSL).
7. sudo rm -Rf resolv.conf (Delete the resolv.conf file).
8. In windows cmd, ps or terminal with the vpn connected do: Get-NetIPInterface or ipconfig /all for get the dns primary and
   secondary. Look for Ethernet adaptor with Description "Cisco AnyConnect...". From under it take values for DNS Servers.
   It has primary and secondary DNS server IPs.
9. Use commands in next two steps by replacing X.X.X.X for values of Primary and Secondary DNS server IPs respectively
10. echo "nameserver X.X.X.X" | sudo tee resolv.conf (Create resolv.conf and append the line.)
11. echo "nameserver X.X.X.X" | sudo tee -a resolv.conf (Append the line in resolv.conf)
12. wsl --terminate  (Terminate WSL in Windows cmd,  from the step 4).
13. sudo chattr +i resolv.conf
14. And finally in windows cmd, ps or terminal:
    Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000

Credit: @MartinCaccia, @yukosgiti, @machuu and @AlbesK:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4246

---

Original resoltuion:

1. Create a file: /etc/wsl.conf.
2. Put the following lines in the file in order to ensure the your DNS changes do not get blown away

[network]
generateResolvConf = false

3. In a cmd window, run wsl --shutdown
4. Restart WSL2
5. Create a file: /etc/resolv.conf. If it exists, replace existing one with this new file.
6. Put the following line in the file

nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Or use your DNS server instead of 8.8.8.8 which is a Google DNS server

7. Repeat step 3 and 4. You will see git working fine now.

Credit: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285#issuecomment-522201021
Sign up for free

Steps are also documented here: https://gist.github.com/akshayhiremath/1b3bff527b3eca6cd41cf60ce88f3a56/8570f9fb4dbd681fc7aabcc817fa18cbab5f1e86#file-fix-wsl2-dns-resolution

I have forked and updated the steps by https://gist.github.com/coltenkrauter to make them easier.

Comment: Do not make people follow a link to learn the answer. Include ALL the steps in the solu here in this post, or this will be removed for being a link-only answer. Links should be left for attribution or further research purposes only.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Detailed steps are added

Comment: I have maintained the links at the end of the answer as a reference. If user follows steps in the answer the problem solves

Answer (score 1):

Another method that is reliable is to use wsl-vpnkit (https://github.com/sakai135/wsl-vpnkit).

The basic setup installs a WSL distro to handle network traffic from your WSL 2 distros (and containers).

Works with Cisco AnyConnect configuration that restricts local network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious but I did not think of this. Another workaround is to install VPN in wsl if that is an option for the VPN you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I was skeptical at first about hsq_roy's method, but since none of the workarounds worked for me I just did what hsq_roy was suggesting.

1. I deleted my Cisco Anyconnect client
2. I reinstalled it via Windows Store.
3. I opened Anyconnect and clicked on manage VPN which forwarded me to the Windows System settings.
4. I set up a new VPN connection within the Windows settings choosing Anyconnect instead of Windows (integrated).
5. I started WSL and it connected to the internet while using a VPN in Windows.
   It works perfectly fine for me, with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Edit your answer to remove the quoted text - totally unnecessary. The `@` don't work in an answer anyway.. so NotTheDr01ds may never see your message/reply. Also, state your process using list formatting to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @kraego worked for me.

I was though unable to make out the adapter from
`Get-NetIPInterface`

but I used instead
`Get-NetAdapter`

And I verified it by looking at the results with and without the VPN connection active.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (no internet when VPN connected) running WSL version 2. To resolve I uninstalled Ubuntu, then from powershell set the default version to WSL 1 when installing a new distro `wsl --set-default-version <Version#>` then re-installed Ubuntu.  That resolved the issue.  To check the WSL versions being used for each distro, from powershell enter `wsl -l -v`

Comment: This does not really explain the reason you had to run WSL1 instances instead of WSL2.  Downgrading to an inferior version of WSL seems like a workaround and an overall inferior solution compared to the other solutions outlined in other answers.

Comment: You can simply convert an existing wsl2 install to a wsl1 install with `wsl --set-version [NAME] 1`

Answer (score 0):

so this works the best way possible!

## after connecting to your vpn

### wsl

---

- open /etc/wsl.conf, add the following

```bash
[network]
generateResolvConf=false
```

- `sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.new      #this is to revert back to the resolv.conf of the wsl when vpn is closed`
- `nano /etc/resolv.conf`
  now add the following:

```bash
nameserver <XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> 
#<dns ip of your vpn> 
#to find this run ipconfig /all in windows powershell admin
```

### windows powershell

```
 wsl --shutdown
 wsl 
 Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
```

Comment: How is this different from other answers?